# MPGS (Mastercard) Integration Security

Tags: javascript, security, mastercard

According to MPGS integration guide, if merchant wants to display receipt when payment completed successfully, MPGS will redirect to merchant site callback URL with the resultIndicator. Merchant site needs to compare resultIndicator with successIndicator stored previously.

Hackers can first launch the MPGS payment session without paying. Then pretend to be MPGS and brute-force attempt repeatedly by calling that merchant site callback URL with different resultIndicator until it matches the stored successIndicator. Merchant then thought that the hacker has paid.

Is this possible? 
If yes, how to avoid this loophole? Need to call Inquiry API when received callback without trusting resultIndicator?

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a situation where the `successIndicator` and `resultIndicator` matched. However, the MPGS merchant portal reported that the transactions were not approved. Upon inquiring with MasterCard, though I was not given a reason for such behavior, I was informed that the team is working on a fix. In addition, I was asked to call the Inquiry API after the transaction.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean the portal should report they were approved instead? Or the indicators were wrong?
MPGS admitted they had a bug and asked you to call Inquiry API after transaction as a workaround? Or they meant calling Inquiry API after transaction is their best practice?

Comment: @bboy Yes the portal should have reported the transactions as approved. MasterCard wanted me to call the Inquiry API until the fix was in place.